# Cumulative average with conditions to update

Tags: r, function, dplyr, data.table

I have a variable (Var.1) that is recorded longitudinally. I want to calculate a cumulative average (or "normal") variable as time progresses. The kicker is that I only want to update the cumulative average when the Var.1 satisfies a condition, in this case it is being >70% of the previous normal. If it satisfies then it should update, if not then the previous value should be carried forward. I was looking for a vectorized solution but am not sure if this is possible.

My sample data is below. I have entered in what the normal should be after excluding the 5th entry (50) given that it does not satisfy the >70% rule.

```
library(tibble)
Sample.GT = tibble(Var.1 = c(80, 80,90,90,50,80,70, 80,80,80),
                   Normal = c(80, 80,83.33,85,85,84,81.67,81.43,81.25,81.11))
```

Dplyr or data.table solutions are preferred. I am looking to implement this with groups across a large data set so a quick solution is ideal.

Answer (score 1):

A possible recursive approach in `data.table`:

```
n <- 1
cs <- GT$Var.1[1L]
GT[1L, cm := cs]
GT[-1L, cm := {
    if (Var.1 > 0.7*cs/n) {
        cs <- cs + Var.1
        n <- n + 1
    }
    cs / n
}, seq_len(GT[,.N])[-1L]]
```

or using `Rcpp` which will be faster:

```
library(Rcpp)
calcNorm <- cppFunction('
NumericVector calcNorm(NumericVector v) {
    int sz = v.size();
    double n = 1.0, cs = v[0];
    NumericVector ret(sz);
    ret[0] = cs;

    for (int i = 1; i < sz; i++) {
        if (v[i] > 0.7*cs/n) {
            cs = cs + v[i];
            n = n + 1.0;
        }
        ret[i] = cs / n;   
    }
    return(ret);
}
')
GT[, newNormal := calcNorm(Var.1)]
```

output:

```
    Var.1 Normal       cm
 1:    80  80.00 80.00000
 2:    80  80.00 80.00000
 3:    90  83.33 83.33333
 4:    90  85.00 85.00000
 5:    50  85.00 85.00000
 6:    80  84.00 84.00000
 7:    70  81.67 81.66667
 8:    80  81.43 81.42857
 9:    80  81.25 81.25000
10:    80  81.11 81.11111
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
GT = data.table(Var.1 = c(80, 80,90,90,50,80,70, 80,80,80),
    Normal = c(80, 80,83.33,85,85,84,81.67,81.43,81.25,81.11))
```

edited thanks to sindri_baldur's comment

Comment: Isn't there a bug? `x <- c(10, 7, 8);calcNorm(x)` updates the second cumulative mean when it shouldn't right?

Comment: Hmm might be v[i] > 0.7*cs/n instead. No comp to check